# How to set all function in python run async

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

Is a any way, all function - builtin or user defined - in Python's module run async.
For example in this code sum, print, f and ...,  all of them run async not sync. Is Python have setting for this?

```
a = sum([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(a)

def f():
    print("Example")
f()
```

Answer (score 2):

They do not run asynchronously. To make code run asynchronously, you can use the asyncio package and add the keyword `async` to the front of your method:

```py
import asyncio

async def sum():
    a = sum(1, 2, 3, 4)
    print(a)

async def f():
    print("Example")

asyncio.run(sum())
asyncio.run(f())
```

You can now, **not** rely on either function to run "first". Both are async and are running in separate threads.
You also have a syntax error at the end of your `print` statement.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

*Note:* If you know Lua or you are aware of what coroutines and tasks are and how they play a role in development, then the docs above should be easy enough to understand.

Comment: I except when run ```for i in range(100000); print('-')``` in async sum function , first f function execute and print "Example" but like sync mode program wait until sum finished and then print Example